# Pass data into array with AAInfographics

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, loops

I'm using AAInfographics to create graphs and I need to pass data into Double arrays to get data visualized.

I'm using next AAInfographics code:

```
    let aaChartModel = AAChartModel()
        .chartType(.column)
        .animationType(.bounce)
        .title("TITLE")
        .subtitle("subtitle")
        .dataLabelsEnabled(false)
        .tooltipValueSuffix("USD")
        .categories(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])
        .colorsTheme(["#fe117c", "#ffc069", "#06caf4", "#7dffc0", "#06caf4"])
        .series([
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Awfull")
                .data(awfull),
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Bad")
                .data(bad),
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Ok")
                .data(ok),
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Good")
                .data(good),
            AASeriesElement()
                .name("Awesome")
                .data(awesome)
    ])
```

And my arrays:

```
var awfull = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
var bad = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
var ok = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
var good = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
var awesome = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I've next model:

```
class MoodRecord: Codable {
    var record = ""
    var dateRecord = Date()
    var selectedMood = Mood.Good
    var pic: Data?
}

enum Mood: String, Codable {
    case Awfull, Bad, Ok, Good, Awesome
}
```

So I need to iterate over

```
var records: MoodRecords!
```

And get correct Mood number for each month. I try to use next code

```
for item in records.items {
        
        switch item.dateRecord.get(.month) {
        case 1:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 0)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 0)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 0)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 0)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 0)
            }
        case 2:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 1)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 1)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 1)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 1)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 1)
            }
        case 3:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 2)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 2)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 2)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 2)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 2)
            }
        case 4:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 3)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 3)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 3)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 3)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 3)
            }
        case 5:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 4)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 4)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 4)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 4)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 4)
            }
        case 6:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 5)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 5)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 5)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 5)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 5)
            }
        case 7:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 6)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 6)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 6)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 6)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 6)
            }
        case 8:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 7)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 7)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 7)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 7)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 7)
            }
        case 9:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 8)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 8)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 8)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 8)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 8)
            }
        case 10:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 9)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 9)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 9)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 9)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 9)
            }
        case 11:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 10)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 10)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 10)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 10)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 10)
            }
        case 12:
            switch item.selectedMood {
            case .Awfull:
                awfull.insert(1.0, at: 11)
            case .Bad:
                bad.insert(1.0, at: 11)
            case .Ok:
                ok.insert(1.0, at: 11)
            case .Good:
                good.insert(1.0, at: 11)
            case .Awesome:
                awesome.insert(1.0, at: 11)
            }
        default:
            print(1)
        }
```

But it's not definitely what I need. Can somebody help me with correct code?

I need to put into each of arrays correct number of mood for current month. For example, if I have 5 awfull moods for January and 3 for February it will be for awfull array:

```
[5.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: It would help if you said what you wanted to happen, and what is actually happening.

Comment: If your code works, it could be factorized, skip the first switch, and do `let monthAt = item.dateRecord.get(.month) - 1; switch item.selectedMood { case .Awfull: awfull.insert(1.0, at: monthAt); case .Bad: bad.insert(1.0, at: monthAt); case .Ok: ok.insert(1.0, at: monthAt); case .Good: good.insert(1.0, at: monthAt); case .Awesome: awesome.insert(1.0, at: monthAt) }`, but it's unclear what you want...

Comment: I need to put into each of arrays correct number of mood for each of months.

Comment: Aaaaahhh... Then, it's not `insert(_:at:)`: `let index = item.dateRecord.get(.month) - 1; switch item.selectedMood { case .Awfull: awfull[index] = awfull[index] + 1.0; case .Bad: bad[index] = bad[index] + 1.0; case .Ok: ok[index] = ok[index] + 1.0; case .Good: good[index] = good[index] + 1.0; case .Awesome: awesome[index] = awesome[index] + 1.0 }` should do the trick... And `bad[index] = bad[index] + 1.0` could be simplified into `bad[index] += 1.0` (same for each one)

Comment: Can you post full answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your switch.

You can avoid the first switch, because it's just "month - 1".

```
let index = item.dateRecord.get(.month) - 1
```

Then, what you want is to add on that index:

```
switch item.selectedMood { 
    case .Awfull: 
        awfull[index] = awfull[index] + 1.0; 
    case .Bad: 
        bad[index] = bad[index] + 1.0
    case .Ok: 
        ok[index] = ok[index] + 1.0
    case .Good: 
        good[index] = good[index] + 1.0 
    case .Awesome: 
        awesome[index] = awesome[index] + 1.0
}
```

Which can be written:

```
switch item.selectedMood { 
    case .Awfull: 
        awfull[index] += 1.0
    case .Bad: 
        bad[index] += 1.0
    case .Ok: 
        ok[index] += 1.0
    case .Good: 
        good[index] += 1.0 
    case .Awesome: 
        awesome[index] += 1.0
}
```